# RewriteRule: /?page=Target&q=1&id=b9dc586

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Having a hard time matching this pattern. The URL has only a query string, there is no web page specified.

Here is the URL to be rewritten:

http://foo.com/?page=Target&q=1&id=b9dc586

This is the URL it should be rewritten too:

http://foo.com/target.php&q=1&id=b9dc586

Thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
RewriteRule ^?page=Target&q=([0-9]*)&id=([a-f0-9]*) target.php&q=$1&id=$2
```

Anyway I think the first '&' in your target URL should be a '?', in that case change the rule in

```
RewriteRule ^?page=Target&q=([0-9]*)&id=([a-f0-9]*) target.php?q=$1&id=$2
```

Comment: thanks wizard, you are correct about the first '&' wants to be '?'!

Comment: Still no joy!  I get an internal server error 500 if I don't escape the question mark with a backslash.  Even still, if I simplify (no additional args) the rewrite rule to 'RewriteRule ^\?page=Target /target.php' it still goes to index.php?

Comment: @George At this moment I cannot try, but if you add index.php to the matching rule what does it do? I mean something like `^index.php\?page=....etc`

Comment: and the following added to .htaccess:RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=target
RewriteRule . /index.php?pagename=target [QSA]